# Doubt in given problem

Tags: probability

Question is
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuvBz.jpg)

Solution is
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2VBO.png)

The underlined text is considered as roots of above equation. Why other root is square of first root ?
In the given question it is given that after squaring roots equation doesn't change but the equation which is given in the solution is not the one which is described in the question.

(Feel free to edit if any)

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image since links can be broken.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

All this is saying is that the equation $\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$ has two roots which can be written as $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$.

Comment: Why we have taken second root as square of first? Why don't we take two different roots ?

Comment: We have got two different roots - they are $\frac{1\pm i\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: Since one of these is the square of the other it's often convenient to adopt the form used in your textbook.